# C++ Fatal Error LNK1120

Tags: c++

I have already looked at the other posts and looked over my program, but I couldn't find Anything that wasn't resolved someway. Also, I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium and this program is for my game that I am making. (It is the developer program which contains how the game works etc.).

```
//Andrew Tew
//Idea.cpp
//Backstory Idea "Seasons Divided"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string StartNavigation;
string Answer;

int Mechanics();
int Backstory();
int Game();
int NewGame();
int LoadGame();
int GameIntro();

int main()
{

system ("cls");

cout << "Seasons Divided Idea Program.\n\n\n";
cout << "Backstory, Game, Mechanics\n\n";
cout << "Navigate To: ";
cin >> StartNavigation;

if (StartNavigation == "Backstory" || StartNavigation == "backstory")
{
    Backstory();
}

if (StartNavigation == "Game" || StartNavigation == "game")
{
    Game();
}

if (StartNavigation == "Mechanics" || StartNavigation == "mechanics")
{
    Mechanics();
}

if (StartNavigation != "Mechanics" && StartNavigation != "mechanics" && StartNavigation != "Game" && StartNavigation != "game" && StartNavigation != "Backstory" && StartNavigation != "backstory")
{
    main();
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
}


int Mechanics()
{

system ("pause");
return 0;
}

int Backstory()
{
cout << "Welcome to The Backstory!\n\n\n";
cout << "Chapters, New\n\n";
cout << "Navigate to: ";
cin >> StartNavigation;


system ("pause");
return 0;
}

int Game()
{
system ("cls");

cout << "Welcome to the Game\n\n\n";
cout << "New, Load, Navigation\n\n";
cout << "Navigate to: ";
cin >> StartNavigation;

if (StartNavigation == "New" || StartNavigation == "new")
{
    NewGame();
}

if (StartNavigation == "Load" || StartNavigation == "load")
{
    LoadGame();
}

if (StartNavigation == "Navigation" || StartNavigation == "navigation")
{
    main();
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
    }

int NewGame()
{
system ("cls");
system ("color 0a");
system ("mode 1000");

cout << "\t\tWelcome!\n\n\n";
cout << "You are about to embark on an adventure packed with Action, Excitement, Love, Sadness, Heroism, and Thrills.\n";
cout << "If you have a record of partypooping, buzzkilling, or being Julian, then this game is not meant for you.\n";
cout << "The game following this is a production of TinyBit Games.\n\n";

cout << "This game is best played in FULL SCREEN MODE. You can easily accomplish this by clicking that empty box in\n";
cout << "the top right corner of the screen, please enjoy.\n\n\n";

system ("pause");
GameIntro();

system ("pause");
return 0;
}

int LoadGame()
{

system ("pause");
return 0;
}

int CompanyIntro()
{
system ("cls");

cout << "\tT";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTi";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTin";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTiny";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyB";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBi";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit G";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Ga";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Gam";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Game";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games P";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Pr";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Pre";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Pres";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Prese";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presen";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Present";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents:";
_sleep(200);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: S";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Se";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Sea";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seas";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seaso";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Season";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons D";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Di";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Div";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Divi";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Divid";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Divide";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");

cout << "\tTinyBit Games Presents: Seasons Divided";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");


main();
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Since you guys wanted a specific Error here's the whole debug

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Idea Game, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Idea.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl GameIntro(void)" (?GameIntro@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl NewGame(void)" (?NewGame@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Idea Game\Debug\Idea Game.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: *"The function main shall not be used within a program"*

Comment: @ouah What do you mean specifically?

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C! Do not add unrelated tags. 2) TL;DR! Provide a [mcve]. 3) Read [ask].

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @ouah Consider it an implementation-defined extension.

Comment: @ouah: One "not" too much in your comment. Just toi add this is one of the differences between C and C++. In C it is not explicitly forbidden.

Comment: That you are not allowed to call `main();` in C++ as per C++ Standard.

Comment: Sorr @Olaf I don't know why C was included in the tags.

Comment: @AndrewTew: Then you should get a new keyboard. It seems to add tags on its own.

Comment: @Immibis I updated the question (bottom) to show the exact error.

Comment: I didn't type my tags I clicked on them @Olaf

Comment: @AndrewTew If you took all of that stuff out of `main` and made them separate functions, then you wouldn't be in the mess of calling `main` (which is illegal in C++).  Instead you would be calling other functions.  You also should give proper indentation to your code, as it is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `GameIntro` function but there is no definition for `GameIntro` in your program. Add it to your source file or if it is already present in another source file ensure it is also compiled and linked to your program.

Also please notice that C++ contrary to C does not allow you to call `main` function in your program.

Comment: WOW, that was a lot simpler than I thought it would be. Thanks :D.

Comment: @AndrewTew your answer was already here in your error message.